# Bootstrap radio buttons misbehaving within scroller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1 with my web page, and I'm trying to style a pair of inlined radio buttons. My understanding is that I do something like this:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" /> Option 1
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" /> Option 2
</label>
```

This works, except if the radio buttons happen to be in a scrollable container. If they are, the inputs seem to be absolutely-positioned such that they don't scroll with the rest of the content (including their labels). Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2v39p7eh/

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: You need to put these elements into a `col-` classes as all `col` say `col-sm-9` classes are having `position:relative`. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/2v39p7eh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting the `div` inside the scrollable container to be `position: relative`:

```
.scroller > * {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naz6pnfd/3/